# How to avoid IllegalStateException when referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a solution that should do something if i am in the middle of a web request or something else if not.

What i am doing is

```
@Autowired private HttpServletRequest request;
```

And then trying to access a variable:

```
request.getRequestURI()
```

But i am getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request...`

I would like to avoid the exception and somehow ask the `HttpServletRequest` weather or not i am in a web request or not.

Is there any way to do it?

Example:
**Additional info:**

> ```
> @Override
> public void trace(String msg) { 
>     if (loggerFactory.isRegisteredUrl(request.getRequestURI())){
>         loggerFactory.getCustomeLogger(request.getRequestURI()).trace(msg);
>         return;
>     }
>     nativelogger.trace(msg);
> }
> ```

Comment: That looks like a design smell to me. Why not use two different beans: one for components handling a request, and another for components not handling requests? Or simply have the caller pass the request, or null, to the method? Could you explan what you're trying to achieve, at a higher level?

Comment: I am overriding the logging of the entire system. i would like to record all logs in a request context in a different logger, cannot be done like you mention with out massive coupling, i added the question to let you see what i am doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably (not tested) use [RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html#getRequestAttributes%28%29):

> Return the RequestAttributes currently bound to the thread.
>
> Returns:
>       the RequestAttributes currently bound to the thread, or null if none bound

So, if the method returns null, the current thread is not handling a request. If it returns a non-null value, it is handling one.

Comment: From nowhere. `getRequestAttributes()` is a static method. So you just call `RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()`.

Comment: will the RequestContextHolder be updated with each request?, because the HttpServletRequest is beeing autowired

Comment: Yes. As the javadoc indicates, it returns the request attributes currently bound to the thread. Each time a request is handled by the Dispatcher servlet, the request attributes are bound to the thread handling this request.